# How can I add a new key value pair to an existing dictionary?

Tags: julia

I have some dictionary that already exists. I want to add a new key-value pair, but I do not want to create a new dictionary from scratch.

How can I add a new key-value pair to an existing dictionary in Julia?

Answer (score 13):

Julia uses the common `dict[key] = value` syntax for setting a key-value pair:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one")
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "one"

julia> dict[2] = "two"
"two"

julia> dict
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"
```

The same syntax will override a key-value pair if the key already exists:

```
julia> dict
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"

julia> dict[1] = "foo"
"foo"

julia> dict
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "foo"
```

`dict[key] = value` is syntax for a [`setindex!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.setindex!) call. Although not as common, you can call `setindex!` directly:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one")
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "one"

julia> setindex!(dict, "two", 2)
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"
```